# Google Chrome Extension HTTPS Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a **google chrome extension**, and i need to send an ajax request to a **https** **rest api**. I was testing this request on **http** page and i was making the request to a **https** page, so it didn't worked because the cross domain posting. So i was searching if the chrome extensions have this "problem" too. Anyone knows if its possible to send a  request to a **https** page from a chrome extension?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your manifest to allow your extension to access any https site.

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html for more info

Comment: If you do this, unload and reload the extension in Chrome's extension manager, I lost about an hour to this.

Comment: @MikeAkers If you are in developer mode and loaded the extension from local drive you have a Reload (Ctrl+R) shortcut in extension manager. You have to reload for almost any change not only for changes in manifest.